# IIS does not run all URL rewrite rules, bails with 404

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

Okay, so I'm trying to do this, but in IIS: [Apache mod_rewrite is removing slashes and generally ignoring my rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24746469/apache-mod-rewrite-is-removing-slashes-and-generally-ignoring-my-rules)

I've successfully imported the rules, and they each work correctly on their own, but for some reason IIS is not running the full list of rules to completion, regardless of whether I have "stop processing" checked or unchecked for each rule. Instead it fails with a 404 after the first matched rule instead of continuing to match subsequent rules, which I believe would result in the correct file found.

Is this some sort of IIS debug setting? Can I do anything about it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use Failed Request Tracing to trace/debug IIS Rewrite rules execution.

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: Got it. The last rule to get the html file wasn't running b/c the path started with a "/" (unlike Apache), so I just tweaked the regex to make an initial slash optional. I still have to create separate rules for URL's with 2 slashes, 3 slashes, 4 slashes, etc. which is highly annoying, but at least it works.